# While installing the ruby using rvm I'm getting the below error

Tags: ruby, rvm

rvm install 2.3.2. While installing the ruby using ram I'm getting the below error.

Screenshot:

[image]

Here is the text:

```
BLRKEC318722D:~ mac_admin$ rvm install ruby-2.3.2   
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.   
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.12/x86_64/ruby-2.3.2.  
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.  
Checking requirements for osx.  
Installing requirements for osx.    
Updating system.........  
Installing required packages: automake, libtool, coreutils, libyaml, readline, libksba....
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install automake libtool coreutils libyaml readline libksba',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/mac_admin/.rvm/log/1497866701_ruby-2.3.2/package_install_automake_libtool_coreutils_libyaml_readline_libksba.log


Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements 
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation  
++ case "$_system_version" in  
++ return 1  
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Comment: Please put the error message as code. don't post images.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions from the message? What was the result?

Comment: ~ mac_admin$ brew doctor  
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers  
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted

Comment: Warning: Your Xcode (7.3.1) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 8.3.3 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.


Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/.bin/har-validator